# storing n numbers of vectors in array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have  n numbers of vectors, that gets generated based upon the user input. I want to store them in an array or vectors .

I am coming from php, and in php u can store arrays inside another array. How can I achieve this in c++. by storing n number vectors inside an array, or inside a vector.

// this is somehow how it can be achieved in php, assuming php has vectors

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i< userInput ; i++)
     {
         arrayOfVectors[] =  vector<string> students_1;

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to use a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<string>> data (userInput);
```

That creates a vector with `userInputs` vectors of string. How you use this depends on your requirements, which aren't clear from the question, a least not to someone unfamiliar with PHP.

Comment: this one works fine, but how can I use iterators on data to cout the values of the vectors stored inside.                                       for (std::vector<vector<string>>::iterator vs=data.begin(); vs!=data.end(); ++vs){ cout<<*vs<<endl;} throws an error.

Comment: @meWantToLearn because the de-referenced iterator is an `std::vector<std::string>`, and there is no output stream operator for that. You would need a nested loop: loop over `vs->begin()` to `vs->end()` printing out each element.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<string>> vectors(userInput);
vectors.push_back(students_1);
vectors.push_back(students_2);
vectors.push_back(students_3);
// an so on
```

Note that boost has [multidimensional arrays](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
typedef vector<std::string> student_vector;
std::vector<student_vector> arrayOfVectors;

for(..)
{
  student_vector student;
  student.push_back("SomeValue");
  student.push_back("SomeValue2");
  arrayOfVectors.push_back(student);
}
```